# Is it possible to load Aurelia templates in javascript and convert to a string

Tags: aurelia

Is it possible to load an aurelia template using javascript and populate it with data manually? I'm creating a leaflet map popup which takes a "content" html string. I'd like to load in a template, populate it with data, and then render it to a string which I can pass to the popup's setContent method.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Aurelia's Dynamic Template Compilation https://github.com/aurelia/framework/issues/102 to solve for this.